# You have an issue in your SQL syntax but don't know the cause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailContent2016
(
    SELECT tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.*
    FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent
    LEFT JOIN tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking ON tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.id = tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.idEmailParam
    WHERE (tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.EmailDate <= "2016-12-31 23:59:59" and tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.EmailDate >= "2016-01-01 00:00:00"); 
);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 6

I don't succeded to find the reason of this error.

Comment: You need to remove the semicolon **>= "2016-01-01 00:00:00");** at the end of the where line

Comment: @nacho I think this could be an answer

Answer (score -1):

In an `INSERT`, parentheses should be used to list columns, not for the query generating the data.

In this case, you seem to know that the data has the same format, so not using the list of columns is okay -- although `create table as` would be better than `insert`.

In any case:

```
INSERT INTO tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailContent2016
    SELECT ec.*
    FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent ec JOIN
         tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking et
         ON et.id = ec.idEmailParam
    WHERE et.EmailDate < '2017-01-01' AND
          et.EmailDate >= '2016-01-01';
```

I also introduced table aliases, which make the query easier to write and read.  This also simplifies the date logic.

This also changes the `JOIN` to an inner join -- the `WHERE` clause is doing that anyway.

To prevent duplicates caused by the `JOIN`, I would use `EXISTS` instead:

```
INSERT INTO tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailContent2016
    SELECT ec.*
    FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent ec
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1           
                  FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking et
                  WHERE et.id = ec.idEmailParam AND
                        et.EmailDate < '2017-01-01' AND
                        et.EmailDate >= '2016-01-01'
                 );
```